# Google map - removing map name

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm styling up a Google map, API 3, and looking to remove the map name that reads "Practice Office" in the label at the top right on the map.

http://new.theredfrog.com/contact/

Is this possible? Here's the snippet of code that refers to the map name.

```
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Practice Office' });
maphull.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
```

Comment: See the documentation on [mapTypeControl](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification)

Comment: Setting it to '' results in a small but unsightly empty box. I've tried flinging it off the page with css too. I'll re-read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation on [mapTypeControl](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification)

```
var options = {
mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: [ 'Styled']
},
    mapTypeControl: false,  
//center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.741365, -0.3361),
center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.775906, -0.736771),
zoom: 9,
mapTypeId: 'Styled'
};
```